# Autofac. Dispose ou não Dispose eis a questão

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, ioc

Existe diferença de performance ou melhores práticas entre os dois exemplos?

**Exemplo1:**

```
private void Teste()
{
    using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        scope.Resolve<MyViewModel>().ShowName();
    }
}
```

**Exemplo2:**

```
private void Teste2()
{
    Resolver.Resolve<MyViewModel>().ShowName();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal é sempre fazer o dispose dos recursos que não serão mais usados. O LifeTimeScope serve justamente para quando são utilizados vários recursos do container e ao fazer o dispose do LifeTimeScope, todos eles são liberados da memória.

Na questão da performance é melhor fazer o dispose.
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html